# How do I send a string from HTML to python using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using flask for I website project and vould like to simply send a  text (or just a string) from HTML to python. I want to do this using python and html only - **no Java Script** if possible. I found a lot of simmilar questions here on stackoverflow but most of them were based on python to html or html to python using JS. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you want form data, then you can get it like

```
from flask import request
var_name = request.form['name_attr']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the form to transfer the data from HTML to the flask. Make input type hidden and set value that you want to pass.